# VBA Macros: Unable to reset recordset in a loop of sql insert query statements (Error: Runtime Error - Automation error and unspecified error)

Tags: excel, automation, runtime-error, vba

I am trying to reduce manual effort of inserting values into the database.

**Problem:** I wish to fetch rows of values from an Excel document and in every iteration, I wish to insert the row values into the database. The for loop gets the data from the Excel sheet, but when I try to execute the query, only the first loop is executing and later it results in an error.

> Error: Run-time Error - Automation Error - Unspecified Error.

I believe the result set is the problem, though I close it, I am unable to refresh it for the next executable insert query.

How to run this loop successfully, inserting rows of Excel data into the database.

source code:

```
{Sub cals()
Dim col1_autog As Long
Dim col2_categorizing As String
Dim col3_stamp As String
Dim col4_defaultB As String
Dim col5_winnumber As String
Dim col6_datetimeval As String
Dim col6_d1 As String
Dim col6_d2 As String
Dim col7_state As String
Dim col8_default1 As Integer
Dim final_query As String
Dim count As Integer
count = 1
Dim x As Integer
Dim dbconnstr As ADODB.Connection
Set dbconnstr = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMainRecord = New ADODB.Recordset
Set objCnTD = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objMainRecord = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
dbconnstr.ConnectionString = "Provider = MSDASQL;Persist Security 
Info=True;Data Source = DSNV;Initial Catalog = RDWBUSTS;
User ID ="***";Password="***""
dbconnstr.Open
x = 1
Do Until x = 4
col1_autog = Sheet6.cells(x, "I").Value
col2_categorizing = Sheet6.cells(x, "A")
Dim col3_stamp_temp1 As String
Dim col3_stamp_temp2 As String
Dim col3_stamp_temp3 As String
col3_stamp_temp1 = "TMC02.S"
col3_stamp_temp2 = ".US"
col3_stamp_temp3 = Sheet6.cells(x, "G")
col3_stamp = col3_stamp_temp1 & col3_stamp_temp2 & col3_stamp_temp3
col4_defaultB = "B"
col5_winnumber = Sheet6.cells(x, "D")
col6_d1 = Sheet6.cells(x, "E")
col6_d2 = Sheet6.cells(x, "F")
col6_datetimeval = col6_d1 & col6_d2
Dim col7_s1 As String
col7_s1 = "Dst=T&Online=T&Dtz=America/"
Dim col7_s2 As String
col7_s2 = Sheet6.cells(x, "G")
col7_state = col7_s1 & col7_s2
col8_default1 = 1
final_query = "INSERT INTO RDWBUSTS.CLOCK_TRAN_PEND_J         
(CTPJ_ID,CTPJ_TYPE,CTPJ_RDR_NAME,CTPJ_IDENT_TYPE,
CTPJ_IDENTIFIER,CTPJ_TIME,CTPJ_EXTRADATA,CLIENT_ID)
Values ( " & col1_autog & ",'" & col2_categorizing & "', 
'" & col3_stamp & "','" & col4_defaultB & "',
'" & col5_winnumber & "','" & col6_datetimeval & "',
'" & col7_state & "'," & col8_default1 & ")"
objMainRecord.Open final_query, dbconnstr
objMainRecord.Close
MsgBox "loop" & x
x = x + 1
dbconnstr.Close
End Sub}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never close the loop.

In your case, the loop start with: `Do Until x = 4`

And must end with : `Loop`

Like this:

```
Do Until x = 4
    'Do stuff
Loop
```

Where you want the end of loop depend from your logic.